# CheckBox All Específico

Tags: php, javascript

Estou utilizando `javascript` em um botão "Marcar Todos" para marcar todos os `checkbox` de meu sistema, porém, agora gostaria de marcar somente os `checkbox` de um bloco especifico ou de uma empresa especifica que define cada bloco. As empresas estão sendo listadas através de um laço, não consigo marcar somente os checkbox de uma empresa específica, está marcando todas.

Alguém tem uma solução?
Desde já, agradeço!

```
 /* Lista Empresas */
                    foreach($listarempresa as $empresa){

                        $listaremail = listarEmails($conexao,$empresa["empresaid"]);
                        ?>

                <!--Oculta Elementos-->
                <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#empresa<?=$empresa["empresaid"]?>").css("display", "none");
                        });
                </script>
                  <div class="collection">
                   <a href="#!" class="collection-item" data-element="#empresa<?=$empresa["empresaid"]?>" style="color:#005129; font-size:13px;"><?=$empresa["empresa"]?><span class="badge">
                                <?=totalEmail($conexao,$empresa["empresaid"])?></span></a></div>

                <div id="empresa<?=$empresa["empresaid"]?>">
                   <?php 
                   $i = 0;
                   ?>
                        <!-- Lista Emails de uma Empresa especifica através da chave empresaid -->
                       <?php foreach($listaremail as $emails){

                    if($empresa["empresaid"] == $emails["empresaid"]){?>

           <p>
               <input type="checkbox"  name = "email<?=$i?>[]" value="<?=$emails["endemail"]?>" id="teste5<?=$i?>" />
               <label for="teste5<?=$i?>" style="font-size:13px"><?=$emails["nome"]." ("?><?= $emails["endemail"].")"?></label>
           </p>              

                <?php $i++; }?>

                 <?php   } ?>


              <div class="switch">
                  <!-- Botão Marcar Todos -->
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="marcarTodos(this.checked);" name="email0[]" id="teste5<?=$i?>">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      <label for="checkall" style="font-size:14px;"></label>
    </label>
             </div>
                      </div>

            <?php  

                    }
```

---

Eu gostaria que ele marcasse somente os emails listados de acordo com a empresa, e ele está marcando todos os emails de todas as empresas.

```
 /* Lista Empresas */
                    foreach($listarempresa as $empresa){

                        $listaremail = listarEmails($conexao,$empresa["empresaid"]);
                        ?>

                <!--Oculta Elementos-->
                <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#empresa<?=$empresa["empresaid"]?>").css("display", "none");
                        });
                </script>
                  <div class="collection">
                   <a href="#!" class="collection-item" data-element="#empresa<?=$empresa["empresaid"]?>" style="color:#005129; font-size:13px;"><?=$empresa["empresa"]?><span class="badge">
                                <?=totalEmail($conexao,$empresa["empresaid"])?></span></a></div>

                <div id="empresa<?=$empresa["empresaid"]?>">
                   <?php 
                   $i = 0;
                   ?>
                        <!-- Lista Emails de uma Empresa especifica através da chave empresaid -->
                       <?php foreach($listaremail as $emails){

                    if($empresa["empresaid"] == $emails["empresaid"]){?>

           <p>
               <input type="checkbox"  name = "email<?=$i?>[]" value="<?=$emails["endemail"]?>" id="teste5<?=$i?>" />
               <label for="teste5<?=$i?>" style="font-size:13px"><?=$emails["nome"]." ("?><?= $emails["endemail"].")"?></label>
           </p>              

                <?php $i++; }?>

                 <?php   } ?>


              <div class="switch">
                  <!-- Botão Marcar Todos -->
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="marcarTodos(this.checked);" name="email0[]" id="teste5<?=$i?>">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      <label for="checkall" style="font-size:14px;"></label>
    </label>
             </div>
                      </div>

            <?php  

                    }
```

Comment: Acredito que mostrar o HTML de como estão os checkbox e seu grupamento poderá ajudar.

Comment: Coloque o código que você esta usando e como se possivel um print de como voce gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: Eu gostaria que ele marcasse somente os emails listados de acordo com a empresa, e ele está marcando todos os emails de todas as empresas. O código está no link:http://pastebin.com/wZVjnix9

Comment: Você tem que relatar se há uma ligação entre o que vai ser marcado e as empresas, assim como uma diferenciação entre as próprias empresas. Isso será setado nos valores de `id` e `rel` do Checkbox